# File close fails

Tags: java, file

I got some problem to close properly a write operation to a file from an EditText.
Since the close() method is put in a finally block, first time I got the error 'cannot resolve...'. Then I forced the statement to be part of the scope.
Unfortunately, now my write operation works only for the first line entered, the others are marked 'null'.
Where must I put the close() statement to not produce any error and write all the lines entered ?
Here is my code :

```
    ajoutarticles =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtajouter);
    btnajouter = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnajouter);

    btnajouter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        //File path  = new File(this.getFilesDir().getPath());
        public void onClick(View v) {

            PrintWriter printWriter = null;
            try {
                choix = ajoutarticles.getText().toString();
                File output2 = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), "shopping.txt");
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(output2.getAbsolutePath(), true);
                BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
                printWriter = new PrintWriter(buffer);
                printWriter.println(choix);


                //Toast.makeText(ListeCourses.this, String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(ListeCourses.this, String.valueOf(choix), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Ligne du fichier = [" + choix + "]");
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Fichier = [" + output2 + "]");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
            } finally {
                printWriter.close(); // Error
            }
        }

    });
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you should put printWriter.close(); above catch clause

Comment: Thanks @Karan,don't you think the close() operation should execute at each iteration of the loop ?

Comment: whats the exception you get ? can you add stacktrace here

Comment: The only trace I get is in logcat, first line I input via EditText is correctly processed, second one ends abnormally with 'null' written to file. How can I manage to close properly the write stream in my code ?. For information, I get a warning in Android Studio at instruction printWriter.close() : java method invocation may produce java.lang.nullpointerexception.Thanks .